# Refactor switch statement to polymorphic code

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring

I would like to remove switch statementm but I don't really know how.

```
/**
 * @return TreeGenerable
 */
public function chooseGenerationStrategy()
{
    switch (true) {
        case $this->isDirectEliminationCompetitor():
            $generation = new DirectEliminationCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
        case $this->isDirectEliminationTeam():
            $generation = new DirectEliminationTeamTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
        case $this->isPlayoffCompetitor():
            $generation = new PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
        case $this->isPlayoffTeam():
            $generation = new PlayOffTeamTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
        default:
            $generation = new PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
    }
    return $generation;
}
```

All methods like `isDirectEliminationCompetitor` are conditions like that:

```
public function isDirectEliminationCompetitor()
{
    return !$this->category->isTeam() && $this->isDirectEliminationType() && !$this->hasPreliminary();
}
```

Any idea how should I improve complexity of this method?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [cyclomatic and npath complexity](https://phpmd.org/rules/codesize.html), your current approach is pretty low with a complexity of 5 for both.

Changing the method to use if statements, the cyclomatic complexity stays at 5 but npath complexity goes up to 16:

```
/**
 * @return TreeGenerable
 */
public function chooseGenerationStrategy()
{
    if ($this->isDirectEliminationCompetitor()) {
        return new DirectEliminationCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
    }

    if ($this->isDirectEliminationTeam()) {
        return new DirectEliminationTeamTreeGen($this, null);
    }

    if ($this->isPlayoffCompetitor()) {
        return new PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
    }

    if ($this->isPlayoffTeam()) {
        return new PlayOffTeamTreeGen($this, null);
    }

    return new PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
}
```

Using elseif instead of if statements lowers them both back to 5, it also makes it much less readible:

```
/**
 * @return TreeGenerable
 */
public function chooseGenerationStrategy()
{
    if ($this->isDirectEliminationCompetitor()) {
        return new DirectEliminationCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
    } elseif ($this->isDirectEliminationTeam()) {
        return new DirectEliminationTeamTreeGen($this, null);
    } elseif ($this->isPlayoffCompetitor()) {
        return new PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
    } elseif ($this->isPlayoffTeam()) {
        return new PlayOffTeamTreeGen($this, null);
    } else {
        return new PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
    }
}
```

The only simplification you can make for this method is to remove the `default` case and return rather than assigning the result to a variable:

```
/**
 * @return TreeGenerable
 */
public function chooseGenerationStrategy()
{
    switch (true) {
        case $this->isDirectEliminationCompetitor():
            return new DirectEliminationCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
        case $this->isDirectEliminationTeam():
            return new DirectEliminationTeamTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
        case $this->isPlayoffCompetitor():
            return new PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
        case $this->isPlayoffTeam():
            return new PlayOffTeamTreeGen($this, null);
            break;
    }

    return new PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen($this, null);
}
```

This maintains a cyclomatic complexity of 5 but drops the npath complexity to 4.

So it seems your current approach is pretty much the most efficient even though it might not exactly seem the best or prettiest.